# Why testing for first character skips empty lines?

Tags: bash

Why does the following file reader and commented line check skip the empty lines?

```
while read line; do
    if [ ! ${line:0:1} == "#" ]; then # leave out comments
            function_call $line
    fi
done < list_items.txt
```

Comment: [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) What's more interesting, is why `[ ! == '#' ]` returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior of skipping empty lines is caused by non-quoting bash variable, always quote when comparing strings:

```
while read line; do
    if [ ! "${line:0:1}" == "#" ]; then # leave out comments
            function_call "${line}"
    fi
done < list_items.txt
```

Above will handle empty lines.

Comment: Also seems that the quotes on the function call arguments - ${line} - make it a single argument, which in my case breaks the function.